# Java JTable select multiple contiguous cells in a single row

Tags: java, swing, jtable, multipleselection

I need to be able to select multiple contiguous cells in a single row only in the `JTable`.

The `SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION` is what works the closest to what I need, but I don't want the possibility to select multiple rows.

Single row, multiple columns is what i'm trying to do.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Set the row's `ListSelectionModel` mode to `SINGLE_SELECTION` and the `ColumnModel`'s `ListSelectionModel` mode to `SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION` and tell the `ColumnModel` that column selection is allowed.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            JTable jTable = new JTable();

            TableColumnModel columnModel = jTable.getColumnModel();
            columnModel.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
            ListSelectionModel columnSelectionModel = columnModel.getSelectionModel();
            columnSelectionModel.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

            ListSelectionModel rowSelectionModel = jTable.getSelectionModel();
            rowSelectionModel.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

            jTable.setModel(createExampleModel());

            createFrameAndShow(jTable);
        }

        private static void createFrameAndShow(JTable jTable) {
            JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("JTable select multiple contiguous cells in a single row");
            Container contentPane = mainFrame.getContentPane();
            contentPane.add(jTable);

            mainFrame.setSize(500, 100);
            mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        }

        private static DefaultTableModel createExampleModel() {
            DefaultTableModel defaultTableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
            defaultTableModel.setColumnCount(4);

            defaultTableModel.addRow(new Object[] { "A1", "B1", "C1", "D1" });
            defaultTableModel.addRow(new Object[] { "A2", "B2", "C2", "D2" });
            defaultTableModel.addRow(new Object[] { "A3", "B3", "C3", "D3" });
            return defaultTableModel;
        }
    }
```

will result in

[image: Column Interval Selection]

Answer (score 1):

You will need this:

```
table.setRowSelectionAllowed ( false );
table.setCellSelectionEnabled ( true );
```

Another way is:

```
table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
```

Using either ways, you can select multiple cells in a row using `Ctrl` key.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need `SINGLE_SELECTION`?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html#SINGLE_SELECTION